# Can you dynamically set a vim shortcut based on file type?

Tags: vim, exuberant-ctags

I have a custom "go to definition" shortcut that works great in python (using ropevim) but when I'm in a coffee-script file I need to use the normal ctags lookup to navigate around. Would it be possible to make just one shortcut that did either a ropevim lookup OR a ctags lookup depending on the file type that is open in the current buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `if`/`endif` tests in your mappings by way of `:execute` but that's a bit messy.

What you should do instead is define your mappings in filetype-specific `autocmd`s (see `:h autocmd`):

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap this that
```

or, better, define them in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` (and another file for coffeescript and so on):

```
nnoremap <buffer> this that
```

Comment: This is `~/.vim/after`,not `~/after`, isn't it?